# Why are crystals of carboxylic acid fluffy

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, crystal-structure, carboxylic-acids

I'm an undergrad student and we recently performed saponification of esters which resulted in the formation of carboxylic acid which we had isolated out of the reaction mixture.
After recrystallisation of the crude sample , the crystals came out to be super fluffy unlike any other crystals of previous compounds we've made yet

Is there a reason to this fluffiness?

Comment: This is know as the "crystal habit": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_habit

Comment: What you observe is the effect of highly different growth rates of the crystallites along the different axes. There are some rules of thumb, but for most molecules, they are very hard to predict.